# Determining whether target is an emulator or phone at runtime

Tags: android, android-emulator

In android, is there a way to determine whether an emulator or a phone is being used at runtime?

The reason: I ask because I am using opengl in my app, which doesn't work on the emulator. So I would like to be able to shut opengl down automatically (or never start it up) when an emulator is used so I can still test the other parts of my app on the emulator.

Comment: Wouldn't it then be smarter to ask "Can I detect whether OpenGL is present" than ask specifically about emulators?

Comment: True, but even if OpenGL is present on the emulator it would be very, very slow (so slow as to probably make my app unusable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(Build.MANUFACTURER.equals("unknown")) {
    // Emulator
}
else {
    // Not Emulator
}
```